# Shamir's Secret Sharing - Proactive and dealer-free

Tags: secret-sharing

I recently started studying about cryptography and I tried to search the internet but I can't find much about these subjects. I want to see the proof of Shamir's Secret Sharing being Proactive and dealer-free .

Later Edit: I found the proof of it being proactive, however I still struggle with the 2nd thing. Basically, if the users know (k,n,p) , how can they compute a secret with none of them knowing it ?

Comment: Does [this paper](http://faculty.eng.fau.edu/nojoumian/Files/DynamicSS.pdf) help?

Comment: I suspect what you are trying to prove is that the parties can make adjustments to defend the secret without the dealer not that there was never a dealer to  begin with.

Comment: Are you asking how any party of $k$ people amongst $n$ knowing each a different $p_i$, for $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ can recover a secret value shared using Shamir's Secret Sharing scheme?

Comment: As @MeirMaor notes, the usual definition of "dealer-free" seems to be that a trusted dealer is not required to *proactively update* the shares, even if such a dealer might be needed to generate the initial shares to begin with. Anyway, if you're asking for a scheme to let *n* semi-honest parties collaboratively generate a (random) $k$-out-of-$n$ shared secret, [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1125) describes one way to do it: basically, each party generates a random secret and shares it with the others using Shamir's scheme, and then everybody sums up the shares they received.

Comment: Anyway, could you please edit your question further to clarify exactly what you're asking? I feel like I could probably answer your question, if I just knew exactly what it was. Hence all these comments.

Comment: Standard secret sharing is not dealer free. However there are some protocols for dealer free initiation. https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/241.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure how much this helps because this is applied research, but this article mentions a system where polynomial secret sharing can be done verifiably without a trusted dealer. You can find it in §5.3.3.
<https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0782/11a74dcb15d2f3844a4971e48e361d68af4f.pdf>