# Multi-party key agreement

Tags: key-exchange

I have done a google search for "multi-party key agreement", and there doesn't seem to be anything more recent than about 2005.

Are there any practical multi-party key agreement protocols known?

To be more precise, I want a protocol which:

- Allows multiple individuals to agree a single shared secret
- An adversary cannot tell what the shared secret is by listening to the communications.
- It should be authenticated so an active adversary cannot persuade a participant to communicate with a secret the adversary knows.

Note: I am aware of [Multi-party Key Exchange protocol from lattice](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61153/multi-party-key-exchange-protocol-from-lattice) but a) that doesn't have any answers; b) I am not only interested in lattice cryptography (in fact, I would prefer something based on ECC or factoring).

Edit: Background
I want a system for encrypting a conference call.  If each caller sends their audio to every other participant with separately agreed keys, then the total amount of work required is $O(n^2)$ (and the work done by each participant is $O(n)$).  If everyone agrees a single shared secret, then we might be able to reduce the amount of work required.

Comment: The first part of your question has the same problem as the other question: it is not a specific question and therefore largely off topic. I think generally cryptographers don't care about the *date* of protocols nor if they are famous or not. Additionally, asking for lists is explicitly off topic. The second part of your question is much better. You fail however to mention *why* lattice based crypto is not acceptable. Those kind of unexplained exclusions tend to put people off (such as the famous: "but I cannot use any libraries" on StackOverflow).

Comment: I don't need a list - I just need a good one.  What I meant about the dates was there were a few papers proposing and knocking down proposals, and then silence.  There are no blog posts "this is how you do multi-party key exchange".

Comment: My preference for factoring/ECC is just that those are much better understood systems.  If no-one has found a problem with an ECC-based protocol, it probably means it is secure.  If no-one has found a problem with a lattice-based protocol, it may just mean that they haven't looked hard enough.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes OTOH, if there is a good lattice-based protocol, I'll take that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically, both the difficulty and the risks involved in securely establishing shared keys in large networks has led to the invention of public-key cryptography. So you might first want to consider using digital signatures/asymmetric encryption instead of sharing the same secret between parties.

If you need all (or some) of the parties to collectively sign or encrypt a message, consider using threshold signature schemes with a [Distributed Key Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_key_generation) protocol. That will produce a key pair that is distributed among $N$ participants such that at least $k$ of them need to collaborate for performing a key operation. For discrete-log cryptosystems there's a [paper by Gennaro et al](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/pubs/stasio/vss.ps.gz) that describes such a setup.

**Edit:** If you only need to establish a common secret (instead of a key pair) between *all* the parties, a simpler solution would be to use a [generalized Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/can-one-generalize-the-diffie-hellman-key-exchange-to-three-or-more-parties) instead. This works for honest participants with insecure communication channels. If the participants can be malicious, a more robust solution is described by [Tseng, 2005](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.106.2329&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Thanks.  That's a couple of useful links.  I think we will stick to pairwise key-agreement.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking on the following protocols:

- Burmester Desmedt
- MD+P
- Asynchronous Ratcheting Tree (bleeding edge)

All of them are called Group Key agreements and most of them assume that each participant is in a circle or are applied on a tree. The security of them is based upon Computational Diffie Hellman but in some cases can be used with Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman.

Answer (score 0):

What ia the problem with doing O(N^2) communication for key exchange. If after that everyone has the same key.
The actual data can be sent only once.

A simple option would be: Everybody publishes a public key.  Everybody picks a random key and encrypts it with everybody elses public key and shares.

Final key is XOR of all sub keys.

only the setup phase uses multiple communication.

Alternatively appoint a dealer which will coordinate a key  among all parties.

Comment: This assumes secure communication channels and honest participants (i.e. issues with man in the middle attacks or participants learning other participants' keys).